# Reformatting a table to save vertical space

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

To save vertical space, how can I convert a $c$ column $r=kn$ row table to a $ck$ column $n$ row table? E.g., a $6=3\cdot2$ row $3$ column table to a $3\cdot3=9$ column $2$ row table;

```
a11 a12 a13
a21 a22 a23
a31 a32 a33
a41 a42 a43
a51 a52 a53
a61 a62 a63
```

to

```
a11 a12 a13 a31 a32 a33 a51 a52 a53
a21 a22 a23 a41 a42 a43 a61 a62 a63
```

TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mat = Array[Symbol["a" <> ToString@# <> ToString@#2] &, {6, 3}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ mat
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a11} & \text{a12} & \text{a13} \\
>  \text{a21} & \text{a22} & \text{a23} \\
>  \text{a31} & \text{a32} & \text{a33} \\
>  \text{a41} & \text{a42} & \text{a43} \\
>  \text{a51} & \text{a52} & \text{a53} \\
>  \text{a61} & \text{a62} & \text{a63} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
mat2 = Join[## & @@ Partition[mat, 2], 2];

mat2 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  \text{a11} & \text{a12} & \text{a13} & \text{a31} & \text{a32} & \text{a33} & \text{a51} & \text{a52} & \text{a53} \\
>  \text{a21} & \text{a22} & \text{a23} & \text{a41} & \text{a42} & \text{a43} & \text{a61} & \text{a62} & \text{a63} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also:

```
 mat3  = Join @@@ Transpose[Partition[mat, 2]];

 mat4 = Join @@@ Multicolumn[mat, {2, Automatic}][[1]]

 mat4  == mat3  == mat2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thanks. After some testing I found ´Transpose[Partition[mat, {Length[mat]/4, 3}]] // TableForm´ to be the answer, where the '4' defines the number of "repetition blocks" of the columns, placed in horisontal direction. Naturally the length of mat must be a multiple of '4', in this case 24, giving a 6 row table.

Comment: I discovered that TeXForm gives a somewhat peculiar output. Is there any way to make this into a tabular format, instead of sub-tabular/arrays inside an array?

Answer (score 7):

Another more complex method :-)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{a11} & \text{a12} & \text{a13} \\
 \text{a21} & \text{a22} & \text{a23} \\
 \text{a31} & \text{a32} & \text{a33} \\
 \text{a41} & \text{a42} & \text{a43} \\
 \text{a51} & \text{a52} & \text{a53} \\
 \text{a61} & \text{a62} & \text{a63} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
 mat={{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}, {a41, a42, 
  a43}, {a51, a52, a53}, {a61, a62, a63}};

    Flatten /@ Transpose@ArrayReshape[mat, {3, 2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 \text{a11} & \text{a12} & \text{a13} & \text{a31} & \text{a32} & \text{a33} & \text{a51} & \text{a52}
   & \text{a53} \\
 \text{a21} & \text{a22} & \text{a23} & \text{a41} & \text{a42} & \text{a43} & \text{a61} & \text{a62}
   & \text{a63} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$